# Lenovo T400 virtualization fails despite set in BIOS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, bios, virtualization

T400 virtualization fails despite set in BIOS

I found this post http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Hardware-Virtualisation-on-E520-with-i5-2540M-2-6GHz/td-p/608633 when I searched on 'T400 Virtualization' - but running through its steps did not help. I have a T400 with the BIOS version 2.16 7VET6WW dated 2009-04-22 with system board vf27k9434tj and the Intel P8600 CPU.

I try to set up virtualization with VirtualBox on Linux Mint 17 'Quiana' but VirtualBox tells me I do not have VT-d enabled, even though it is enabled in the BIOS, and I have cycled power since changing the BIOS.

vmx is enabled per "grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo"

No supervisor password is set. The RAM matches, a pair of 2GB modules.

How can I get virtualization to permit use of multiple CPUs?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P8600 CPU was said on another forum not to support VT-d. They fibbed.

Got everything working by

Reboot into BIOS settings
 Restore to defaults
 Enable virtualization
 Power down
 Remove power cord
 Remove battery from laptop
 Hold down power button 30 secs by the clock to drain any remaining capacitors
 Battery in, power cord in
 Power up